# Dealing with multiple items at once in a single window

Tags: gui-design

I am working on a web app in which one of the features requires a taxi operator to respond to/make multiple customer haggle (barter) requests for a fare. This all needs to take place within a single window. This is what I have come up with so far:

[image]

The issue that I am having here is that this appears to be a "fidgety" way of dealing with multiple items at once, as the operator needs to scroll through each job, make their selection and then click on the **Respond** button. As a result, it is difficult to manage each and every single job.

Is there a more elegant way of dealing with this?

The required tasks of the operator are as follows:

- The operator can respond to or set a haggle quote.
- When responding to a haggle quote, they can either accept/reject it, or set their own quote
- Both operator/customer only have 3 attempts to haggle back and forth, after which they can send no more quotes to each other

A job can have one of three states to Respond to:

- No haggling can take place, as attempts by operator/customer have been used up
- Awaiting a response from the operator to customer's quote
- Awaiting operator quote

Comment: Why don't you make a big list with a search box on top on let the users pick their items using a normal click? rhe naviour toggles so if the user makes a mistake he can click on that user again to unchose it. Better show an alphabetic list on the Bottom or the right side of the box, because the User wont see the chosen items while searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a [badge](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges) that shows the current bid directly on the job list item.  If it's the operator's turn to respond, add checkmark or x buttons to accept or reject.  If reject is clicked and there are remaining haggles, provide the new bid input on the right.  This way, the operator can respond directly from the list -- one click in the case of accept actions and final reject action.